# Top bar is overlapping instead of pushing down?

Tags: css

I'm working on a site right now and can't really figure out what exactly is happening.  You can view the page here:  http://demo.easythemepro.com/?themedemo=AnimeStar

If you look at the top bar where you can switch themes, you'll see that it's actually overlapping with the website instead of pushing the entire thing down.  What exactly needs to be changed to fix this?

I've tried changing everything from the PHP to the HTML to the CSS and it keeps happening.  I know it's problem something extremely simple that I'm just overlooking after staring at this code for so long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's set to `position: fixed`.

```
#wpthemedemobar {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Which means the element is positioned relative to the browser window. You can change it to `relative` and it should flow with the page content.

Comment: Is there a way to keep it fixed but still knock down the other content though?

Comment: Give the body `padding-top` that's the same height of the bar. That will allow the bar to remain at `position: fixed`, and force the body content to move down the same pixel amount.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add a fixed topbar without over lapping the site you will have to use an iframe to contain the theme.